# What is the different between JPlugin and \Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin

Tags: development, plugin

I was learning plugin development when I came across this.

so for some plugin, I see

```
class pluginA extends JPlugin
```

for some others, I see

```
class plgGantryEasyblog extends \Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin
```

Are they the same thing? If not, what is the difference? I can't find documentations about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JPlugin` is an alias of `Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin`. It is the same thing at the moment, but one should start using fully qualified class names because all aliases in Joomla! are deprecated and will be removed in the future - a few in 4.0 and everything else in 5.0.

Relevant PHP documenation: [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).